# Python : How to get value of dynmaic row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to python and kivy.
I am trying to get value of dynamic row.But now i am getting value like this

```
Column2
Column1
```

Can someone tell me how to get value like this ?

```
1,column1,column2
2,column1,column2
```

Because i have three column in my database table like id,name,value and i want to insert value in database table through loop
I am using this code

```
def insert_value(self):
        values = []
        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):

            for ch in row.children:
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    values.append(ch.text)
        lenArray = len(values)

        for x in range(0, lenArray):
            print (values[x])
```

## demo.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert_value(self):
        values = []
        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):

            for ch in row.children:
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    values.append(ch.text)
        lenArray = len(values)

        for x in range(0, lenArray):
            print (values[x])



class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    id = ObjectProperty(None)



class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count),id=str("test"+str(self.row_count))))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        text:"Column1"
        size_hint_x: .8

    TextInput:
        text:"Column2"
        size_hint_x: .8
display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'


        Rows:
            id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.insert_value()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain a structure we must create a list of lists, then in each list the first parameter is the text of the Button that we filter through `isinstance()`, and the other elements are concatenated.

```
[...]
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert_value(self):
        values = []
        rows = self.ids.rows

        for row in reversed(rows.children):
            vals = []
            for ch in reversed(row.children):
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    vals.append(ch.text)
                if isinstance(ch, Button):
                    vals.insert(0, ch.text)
            values.append(vals)

        for val in values:
            print("{},{},{}".format(*val))

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a `ListProperty` to your `Row` class that stores the values of the row in the order you want, which makes it easier to obtain them later.

You can use a `ListView` to show the rows.

**Demo.kv:**

```
<Row>:
    values: row_id.text, col1.text, col2.text
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 30

    Button:
        id: row_id
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        id: col1
        text:"Column1"
        size_hint_x: .8

    TextInput:
        id: col2
        text:"Column2"
        size_hint_x: .8

<Rows>:
    content: content
    BoxLayout:
        id: content
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

Display:
    rows: rows
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'


        Rows:
            id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.insert_value()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

**Demo.py:**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (450, 525)


class Display(Screen):
    rows = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Display, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_more(self):
        self.rows.add_row()

    def insert_value(self):
        values = [row.values for row in reversed(self.rows.content.children)]
        for row in values:
            print(row)


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    id = ObjectProperty(None)
    values = ListProperty()


class Rows(ScrollView):
    row_count = 0
    content = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_row)

    def add_row(self, *args):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.content.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count),
                                id="test" + str(self.row_count)))


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('Demo.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```